# Angular - How to randomly select an image in the folder to set background

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to randomly select an image in the folder to set background. 
I'm newbie, this is my code:

```js
app.directive('randomBackground', function($http){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'images/background'}).success(function(data) {
         console.log(angular.element(data)[11]);
         var imgs = [];
   ...
         var url = imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
         element.css({
             'background-image': 'url(images/background/'+url+')',
             'background-size' : 'cover',
             'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat',
             'background-attachment' : 'fixed',
         });
  });
    };
});
```

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: I do not know what to do in that "..." to retrieve the file name for imgs []

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cver/ryovp7h4/

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/1DjrVbUFdTovxu5rKL95?p=preview
check this plunker
from what i see its or err with the url or its with the angular set up (ng-app or references adding) regards

Comment: but I have many images and I want to randomly select one of them

Comment: this is just an idea but you can always pass param to directive or do as @Anas Omar said by passing the full image url

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ryovp7h4/6/

Answer (score 0):

basically you are looking for a way to get the images paths from the folder `images/background` (please correct me if i am wrong), which is not doable cause angularjs, and javascript in general a client side, so you have to get the files names from the servers side and send the array to the client side, then you can do your magic :)

Comment: I'm just going to do a simple web page without any server side, so what can I do

Comment: in this case you need to put the images paths static in an array like this 
`var imgs=['img1','img2','img3',.....]`

Comment: and each time to change the image in images/background, I have to update the list? I like automatically but if that is not good, I will use this way, thank you!